# See if string contains substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I was looking for a way to write code that checks whether a certain string is a part of another string. I understand that it is easy to do when we have numbers, but I don't know how to do it with strings.

For example, I have this function

```
a = is_part("motherland", "land")
```

I need to know that `"land"` is a part of the word `"motherland"` (return `True` or `False`). Is it possible to check this?

UPDATE: How can I create a restriction when the second word always has to be in the end of the first one. For example, in case when I check whether "eight" is a part of "eighteen" it returns False because "eight" is not at the end of the first word

Comment: Yes, it certainly is.

Comment: @vaultah Could you please give a hint how this can be implemented in a code?

Comment: It's called "searching", "matching", "collation" and you could easily duckduckgo lots of example code. That said, type `help(string)` in an interactive session to get an idea of what functons the `string` class supports.

Comment: About the UPDATE: Geez, look at the docs already. That's yet another functionality already there for you to just use and it even has the obvious name.

Comment: Btw, you say this is easy to do with numbers, but I don't see how. Can you show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that determines whether a string `target` is contained within another string `some_string`.

```
def is_part(some_string, target):
    return target in some_string

>>> is_part('motherland', 'land')
True
>>> is_part('motherland', 'father')
False
>>> is_part('motherland', '')
True
```

If you don't like an empty string returning true, change the return statement to

```
return (target in some_string) if target else False
```

If, on the other hand, you need to implement it yourself:

```
def is_part(some_string, target):
    if target:
        target_len = len(target)
        for i in range(len(some_string)):
            if some_string[i:i+target_len] == target:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! Another question, if you don't mind, how can I create a restriction like the second word always has to be in the end of the first one. For example, in case when I check whether "eight" is  a part of "eighteen" it returns False because "eight" is not at the end of the first word

Comment: @SteveLee: consider using regular expressions to match the end of a word, or iterate over all words and use `endswith()`.

Answer (score 8):

This should help:

```
>>> "land" in "motherland"
True
>>> "banana" in "motherland"
False
```